# Mostrar alerta después de eliminar JQUERY / PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola espero que estén muy bien.

Tengo la siguiente duda estoy utilizando PHP para eliminar los registros de mi tabla por allí todo bien la funcionalidad está bien, la duda nace cuando utilizo Jquery para disparar una alerta para que el usuario visualice que se está eliminando el registro que el escogió.

**¿Qué pasa?**
Que la alerta se **dispara solamente** cuando se quiere eliminar el registro que queda de primero y **no** se dispara cuando se desea eliminar los demás registros, es decir, yo inserto 3 registros en mi bd (registro 1, 2 y 3) y luego los listo en mi tabla **ahora**... cuando yo doy click en eliminar por ejemplo registro 1 me sale la alerta ya que es el primer registro de mi tabla, una vez eliminado si yo quiero eliminar el último registro (registro 3) me lo elimina **pero** no me sale la alerta.

**¿Existe alguna forma de hacerlo de manera dinámica?**
Intenté colocando el atributo `onclick` en el boton de eliminar pero sin resultados positivos.

Acá está el código:

**Jquery**

```
$('#eliminarRegistro').on('click',function(e){
     alertify.alert('Eliminando, por favor espere...');
});
```

**Boton con el cual elimino**

```
<a id='eliminarRegistro' href='../controlador/eliminar-aldea-controlador.php?id=".$aldea['id_ald']."'><img src='../vista/recursos/img/delete.png' alt='Eliminar'></a>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme muchas gracias.

Comment: Creo que el problema los tienes en el botón. ¿Creas un botón para cada registro?

Comment: No brother, tengo el botón dentro de un foreach y ese botón se repetirá según la cantidad de registros que liste en mi tabla

Comment: ¿Y esos diferentes botones tienen el mismo id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en el botón, no repitas nunca los `id` en un elemento html, y el href deberías montar-lo diferente...

Te pongo una posible solución:

```
<a class='eliminarRegistro' href='../controlador/eliminar-aldea-controlador.php?id='.$aldea['id_ald'].'><img src='../vista/recursos/img/delete.png' alt='Eliminar'></a>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias compadre, resuelto, gracias por el consejo.